# Is there any alternate method to install phpmyadmin in phytec board other than using 'sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin'?

Tags: yocto, phpmyadmin

I am currently trying to install phpmyadmin in phytec board. I have installed Yocto OS for this board.

The installation procedure commands like `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` fails and `"Package 'phpmyadmin' has no installation candidate"` response is being received for that command.

I am looking for some other alternate method to install phpmyadmin. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: `phpmyadmin` is a famous package and should have how to install section in their website or in the readme of the package itself. You may consult those manuals.

Comment: Without using commands ? you mean like an exe installer on Windows ? No. Because you have to understand that having phpmyadmin install mean configuring `php` and apache2 for your system, then install a virtualhost for phpmyadmin. Tries `apt-cache search php` and see if there's any package with this name or you will have to setup everything on your own.

Answer (score 2):

You ask, "*Is there any alternate method to install phpmyadmin other than using commands?*"

No.

Comment: I wouldn't close it out, maybe it can be an integrated module of some web-based management software. Although in this case, it is more like a software recommendation question.

Comment: @peterh quite, but we would need some inkling of what that web-based or GUI management software - which would already have to be installed - was. The information in the question is fairly obscure, in that respect. This is a general-purpose site... I don't know what Yocto images (or installers?) are floating around for this specific board. E.g. posting specific links would be helpful.

Comment: Upvoted for being short and concise.